# Converting float to binary in MIPS

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips, mips32

I'm writing a code for an assignment and I need to convert a decimal number to its IEEE754 representation. For example: input "8.855" and output "0 10000010 00011011010111000010100".
I store the number in a float register and try to print each digit but i can´t get it. 
here is my code:

```
.text
main:
li.s $f0 -0.855 #load floating point immediate
mfc1 $t8 $f0 #store in $t8

#extract bit 31 --10000000000000000000000000000000--
and $a0, $t1, 0x80000000
srl  $a0 $a0 31

#print sign
addi $v0 $zero 1
syscall

#print space
addi $a0 $zero 32
addi $v0 $zero 11
syscall

#extract bits 23-30 --01111111100000000000000000000000--
and $a0, $t1, 0x7F800000
srl  $a0 $a0 23

#print exponent
addi $v0 $zero 1
syscall

#print space
addi $a0 $zero 32
addi $v0 $zero 11
syscall

#extract bits 0-22 --00000000011111111111111111111111--
and $a0, $t1, 0x003FFFFF

#print mantissa
addi $v0 $zero 1
syscall

#print new line
addi $a0 $zero 10
addi $v0 $zero 11
syscall

jr $ra
```

I think that my code get the wrong position, but i'm not pretty sure. Any ideas??
Thanks all!! :D

Comment: You're printing the values in decimal form. Which is fine for the sign part, because it will be 0 or 1. But for the other parts you should use a loop to print each bit separately.

Comment: how can i load each bit?

Comment: The same way you're isolating the sign bit. You just need to do that in a loop, and shift either the mask or the value being masked.

Comment: using <lbu $a1 $a0>, saving each bit in $a1 and print it? is it correct? i am so confused of why if i´m managing these parts in a int(i handle the int position by position) , it has to print it in decimal and no in binary..

Comment: You are using syscall 1 which prints in decimal. Syscall 34 will print in binary. http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html

Comment: But it is a syscall exclusive of the program Mars, and they ask me to do it in Qtspim.. :(